# How to keep URLs in android xml resource file?

Tags: android, xml, url, android-resources

I would like to keep human readable URLs in my `strings.xml`. Some URL contain symbol `&`. Of course, I could replace that with `%26`. But then when I apply url encode to the string,  `%26` will be replace wiith `%2526` and I'll get wrong url. Is there any way to avoid that?

Upd. I am supposed to have url where another url (taken from resource file is parameter), like:

```
http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Some+text&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com
```

Comment: putting url on String.xml and showing at run time,i think in such manner if you put url on String.xml in this case you have to replace lots of charectors as url some time contains any unpredictable symbols such as "-","_","$","&" etc...this will increase your number of conditions and this is headech task,better you should make on comman class in which all url will be there defined by string data type,and in this case you don't have to replace charectors etc....

Answer (score 3):

You should encode `&` as `&amp;`.

Some other useful, predefined entities in XML are:

- `&quot;` for a double quote (`"`)
- `&lt;` for a "less than" sign (`<`)
- `&gt;` for a "greater than" sign (`>`)

Note that you should put the trailing colon (`;`).

Here is the [complete list](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php) for html escape characters.

Comment: But it also doesn't work - `URLEncoder.encode("http://example.com?a=1&amp;b=2")` returns `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Fa%3D1%26amp%3Bb%3D2`, i.e. `&amp;` is replaced with `%26amp%3B`.

Comment: @LA_ - You don't need to do `URLEncoder.encode()` - you can just store it as it is - just encode ampersand.

Comment: I've updated my question to demonstrate that I have to apply `URLEncoder.encode()`. In my example `http:\\stackoverflow.com` should be stored in the resource file.

Answer (score 0):

@kamituel answer is right, otherway if you really need them as human readable you could store them in static final variables.